# How to test a function which must infinitely loop in some cases?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am facing a problem, I have developed a function that must, in some cases, end in an "infinite loop".
Here is an example:

```py
def my_function(a=False):
    if not a:
        return True
    else:
        while True:
            pass
```

In order to test my code, I need to deal with this function.
I know the [Halting concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) so I want my test to wait *5 seconds* for a return value.
If there is not, it must shut down the function and return a specific value `'is_looping'`.

For this, I want to use the python mock.

To give you and idea, I share you this code:

```py
import pytest
import mock

def my_function(a=False):
    if not a:
        return True
    else:
        while True:
            pass

def test_my_function():
    my_function=mock(return_value='is_looping')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(['-vv'])
```

My problem is that I don't know how to tell my mock object to adopt this comportment.

Can you help me? Have you got another solution that fits my requirements?

Comment: "a function that must, in some cases, ends in "infinite loop"" *Why*? What problem do you solve this way? How do you intend to get a result from the code in this case? What is the significance of the loop? Strongly consider whether you can redesign the code for better testability. Alternately, if this loop *drives UI* (e.g. repeatedly asks the user for input and dispatches to other functions), that might just not be the sort of thing that's a good fit for automated testing (unit-test the other functions instead).

Comment: You mock things *in* the function you want to test; you don't mock the function itself.

Comment: The function my_function is an example (In my case, my function create a filename that is not existing in a specific folder based on os.urandom number. For test purpose, I set the result of os.urandom -> 42. For os.uradom=42, my function returns me a specific filename but because it exists and os.random is fixed, my function is in while loop, which is the correct behavior)

My code seems to be correct :)